# Convert SAS mixed procedure to R

Tags: r, sas, mixed-models

I'm currently struggleing with some mixed models for repeated measures with R. I have read a lot of post and request for conversion of code from SAS to R, and I have found some elements but I am not sure of what I have done so far.

I am trying to model the effect of some products on subjects with different sequences patterns and different visits (following the pattern 1 product by visit).

I have some SAS code which is the "ground truth" and I would found the same results obtained by SAS with R ( with nlme package or equivalent) to display it through a Shiny App.

I've tried some models with R, with some results close to the one from SAS but some parts are still different, especially AIC, BIC and LogLik.

Below is the SAS code that I try to convert in R and my R implementation :

**SAS Code**

```
Proc mixed data = data method = reml;
Class A B C D;
Model variable = B C D  / solution ddfm = kenwardroger ;
Random A(B);
etc.
etc.
Run;
```

**R Code**

```
library(nlme)


 model <- test.lme <- lme(variable~ B + C+ D, 
random = ~ 1| A / B, data = data, na.action = na.omit)
```

A : Subject ID
B : sequence pattern
C : visit number
D : product used

Is my conversion to R correct ? If it is, why I get different results in AIC, BIC and LogLik ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Often this is partly due to the parameterization methods used, in the CLASS statement in SAS and ensuring it's handled the same way in R.

Comment: @Reeza I've read that the CLASS statement in SAS ensure that the folowwing variables are treated like factors with multiple levels isn't it ? In this purpose I've paid attention to use A, B, C and D as factors (ordered or not) but results are still the same

Comment: How you create those factors can differ, there are different parameterization methods, GLM and Referential being the most common.

Comment: @Reeza I've just turned A, B,C and D into factors with as.factor(data$A) etc. Am I wrong ?

Comment: No idea how R does the coding to be honest, just know that any time I've ever had to log into these issues it comes down to a default setting that's different or different parameterization.

Comment: @Reeza I understand, I'll continue to search in that way thank you